# Different output each time on multiple threads

Tags: c, multithreading, posix, conditional-statements, mutex

I keep getting different output each time this program is run. Also, the program never terminates, but stops using the cpu. I am not sure what is going on.

It is supposed to read a file, one character at a time, write it to a buffer, and output it if the character is a function character. Each thread handles one job of reading, writing, and outputting.

The program outputs different characters each time.

Can someone help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>


// Global variables(s) / Shared data
FILE *filePointer;
char input;
char buffer[60] = {'\0'};

// Condition variable(s)
pthread_cond_t characterInput;
pthread_cond_t printingLine;

bool charRead = false;
bool printBuffer = false;

// Mutex to control access to shared data.
pthread_mutex_t lock;

/*
 Thread 1:
 Reads input one character at a time.
 Passes the read character to Thread 2 before another is read.
*/
void *readCharacter(void *arg)
{
    // Begin Critical section
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    // Receive the character from the user.
    if ((input = fgetc(filePointer)) == EOF) pthread_exit(NULL);

    // Let the other threads know a character has been received.
    charRead = true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&characterInput);

    // End Critical section
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/*
 Thread 2:
 Stores characters as received.
 However, these characters ask Thread 2 to take action:

 * – erase last character from buffer

 @ – insert an end-of-line marker into buffer

 $ – delete the last word

 & – remove current incomplete line from buffer
*/
void *receiveCharacter(void *arg)
{
    int bufferIndex = 0;

    // Begin Critical section
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    // Wait to receive a character.
    if (!charRead) pthread_cond_wait(&characterInput, &lock);
    charRead = false;

    // Check to see if the character is an action.
    switch (input) {
        case '*':
            buffer[bufferIndex--] = '\0';
            break;

        case '@':
            buffer[bufferIndex] = '\0';
            // Signal to print the buffer.
            printBuffer = true;
            pthread_cond_signal(&printingLine);
            break;

        case '$':
            while (bufferIndex >= 0 && buffer[bufferIndex] != ' ')
            {
                buffer[bufferIndex] = '\0';
                bufferIndex--;
            }
            break;

        case '&':
            while (bufferIndex >= 0)
            {
                buffer[bufferIndex] = '\0';
                bufferIndex--;
            }
            break;

        default:
            buffer[bufferIndex] = input;
            bufferIndex++;
            break;
    }
    // END Critical Section
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/*
 Thread 3:
 Reads complete lines of characters (an end-of-line character is read).
 Prints the read line and removes it from the buffer.
*/
void *printLine(void *arg)
{
    // Begin Critical section
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    // Wait for the signal to print the buffer.
    if (!printBuffer) pthread_cond_wait(&printingLine, &lock);
    printBuffer = false;

    // Print the whole buffer.
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c", buffer[i]);
        buffer[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }

    // End Critical section
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

// Creates Threads 1, 2, and 3.
int main()
{
    // Thread 1, 2, and 3.
    pthread_t threadOne;
    pthread_t threadTwo;
    pthread_t threadThree;

    // Initialize the mutex.
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) perror("Mutex error.\n");

    // Open the file.
    filePointer = fopen("homework4.txt", "r");

    // Wait for the threads to execute.
    while (input != EOF)
    {
        // Create and run the three threads.
        pthread_create(&threadOne, NULL, readCharacter, NULL);
        pthread_create(&threadTwo, NULL, receiveCharacter, NULL);
        pthread_create(&threadThree, NULL, printLine, NULL);
        if(pthread_join(threadOne, NULL) != 0) perror("Join error.\n");
        if(pthread_join(threadTwo, NULL) != 0) perror("Join error.\n");
        if(pthread_join(threadThree, NULL) != 0) perror("Join error.\n");
    }

    // Close the file.
    fclose(filePointer);

    // Destroy the mutex as it is no longer needed.
    if (pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock) != 0) perror("Destroy Mutex Error.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide your `homework4.txt` for testing?

Comment: And do you have to create a thread only to read one character? There are two possible solutions: 1) create 2 threads each time and create the 3rd one for printing only when `input=='@'` in `receiveCharacter`; 2) create 3 threads, one for reading, one for receiving and the 3rd one for printing. Use loops in each of the thread and leverage mutexes and conditional variables to ensure the execution ordering is reading=>receiving=>reading=>receiving(=>printing when `@` is received)=>reading=>receiving=>...

Comment: `char input` should be `int input`.   `EOF` may not fit in a `char`.

Comment: homework4.txt contains...                                                               hi$hii*@How are are&How are you
All the best.
this line will not be printed.    ...                                                                                It should print "hi

How are you

All the best."

Comment: I have tried to just create thread 3 when input is equal to '@' but now the program does nothing... :/